# How to replace a line containing specific text in a PDF file using Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace a line containing "SIK" in a PDF file using Python.

Here's my code:

```py
import os
import fitz

search_text = "SIK"
replace_text = "Test"

for file_name in os.listdir():
    if file_name.startswith("ATTBill") and file_name.endswith(".pdf"):
        pdf_file = fitz.open(file_name)
        found = False
        for page in pdf_file:
            draft = page.search_for(search_text.strip())
            if draft:
                found = True
                for rect in draft:
                    annot = page.add_redact_annot(rect,text=replace_text)
                page.apply_redactions()
                page.apply_redactions(images=fitz.PDF_REDACT_IMAGE_NONE)
            if found:
                output_file_name = file_name.replace('0604', '')
                pdf_file.save(output_file_name, garbage=4, deflate=True)
        print(found)
        pdf_file.close()
```

It is not able to replace my text with the same font as SIK

Comment: What happens when you run your code? How does the result differ from what you want?

Comment: This gives me 4 boxes like invalid characters and not Test. Could you suggest something that maintains the original font and size and just replaces the text?

Comment: makes sense. so is there a way to get the original font and size so I can replace text with that?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/search.html?q=merge_content_streams&check_keywords=yes&area=default) I don't see the function `merge_content_streams` anywhere including as a method on PageObjects. You're going to have to try and replicate whatever you want that function to do with a different one or on your own. If you post where you found it people might be able to help more.

Comment: updated the code and the title and the error. please go over it again

Answer (score 1):

By adding the parameter text to the add_redact_annot like the code below, the "SIK" will be replaced by "SUR".

```
annot = page.add_redact_annot(rect,text=replace_text)
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. How do I maintain/clone the font of the existing and replaced text?

Comment: Maybe you can extract the font of the existing page and use it when adding new text, something like this code: annot = page.add_redact_annot(rect,text=replace_text,fontname=page.get_fonts()[0][4])

Comment: This gives me 4 boxes like invalid characters and not Test. Could you suggest something that maintains the original font and size and just replaces the text?